# How can I fix a shower door that doesn't seal?

Tags: bathroom, shower

My shower door used to seal perfectly, I could slam it and it would stay shut. Lately, it has now started flapping around and not sticking. [Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhzApqd8Iu0&feature=youtu.be). Can anyone put me down the right path to fix this?

Comment: It appears the catch has failed. As in something in the mechanism has broken. What that is would determine the course for repair.

Comment: Does it seal when you don't slam it?

Comment: It does seal (using a magnetic strip) if I carefully close it